# Malloc fails with errno 12

Tags: c, file-io, malloc, sizeof

I read/write data into a custom raw file where I used to write

```
version (int)
data
```

I implemented a more generic way to write my data and now the expected format is

```
headersize (size_t)
header (headersize)
data
```

Therefore, I manually added `4` (`sizeof(int)`) to an old raw file (with `ghex`) to make it compatible with the new implementation.

---

Now, my program is failing when `malloc`-ing space for a `header_p` on which I want to read the `header` from the raw file.

```
size_t headersize;
fread(&headersize, sizeof(size_t), 1, fd);
printf("%p\t%d\n", header_p, (int) headersize);
header_p = malloc(headersize);
printf("%p\t%d\t%d\t%s\n", header_p, (int) headersize, errno,strerror(errno));
```

Returns

```
(nil)   4
(nil)   4   12  Cannot allocate memory
```

---

Why would `malloc` fail on such operation? The `headersize` seems correctly hard-written in the raw file since it's equal to `4` and `errno` of `12` seems to indicate that I don't have enough memory but when I hard-code `sizeof(int)` at the `malloc` call, the failure doesn't occur anymore.

```
size_t headersize;
fread(&headersize, sizeof(size_t), 1, fd);
printf("%p\t%d\n", header_p, (int) headersize);
header_p = malloc(sizeof(int));
printf("%p\t%d\t%d\n", header_p, (int) headersize, errno);
```

Returns

```
(nil)   4
0x8e6e90    4   0
```

I suspect that the `errno` of 12 hides something else but I don't understand what.

Comment: how is `headersize` in code defined?

Comment: `printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));` will tell you more.

Comment: read from file : `fread(&headersize, sizeof(size_t), 1, multifile->fd)`

Comment: what is the type of headersize in code I meant

Comment: You can you `perror()` in order to get you error message in stderr.

Comment: @gio meant to ask the _data type_ of `headersize` variable.

Comment: @mch `Cannot allocate memory`

Comment: @gio `size_t headersize;`

Comment: 12 should be `out of memory`.

Comment: are you checking that `fread()` returned `1`? With @mch comment I now suspect that `headersize` is not initialized because `fread()` failed.

Comment: I updated the code with the casting of `size_t headersize` into an `int` for printing

Comment: If you want a better test, assign headersize = sizeof(int), and then try the malloc

Comment: @Jav, try using `ssize_t` for the `headersize` variable, and use the appropriate specifier `"%ld"`, and see if the value is negative.

Comment: to be even more correct you need to use `(void*)header_p` inside printf

Comment: Just to test if the value is negative...

Comment: convert to `unsigned long` if you're stuck with a C89 compiler: `printf("%p\t%lu\n", (void *) header_p, (unsigned long) headersize);`. If you have a C99 compiler use `"%zu"` instead: `printf("%p\t%zu\n", (void *) header_p, headersize);`

Comment: `fread(&headersize, sizeof(ssize_t), 1, fd); printf("%ld,headersize);` returns `12884901892`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is your problem. `sizeof(size_t)` must take the pointer size, and may/may not be `sizeof(int)`. If you print it with the `(int)` cast, it looks okay, because only the least significant 4 bytes (in your case) are evaluated. If you use it for `malloc()` then the whole `size(size_t)` is used, and it's either garbage or part of your header.

When you're pickling numbers, you should:

- Worry about endianness, and convert it to either little/big endian (or leverage [hton*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) from `arpa/inet.h`)
- Use specific-width integers from [stdint.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html), never ever pickle a type without specified width